# Joomla Akeeba Fatal error

Tags: joomla, components, upgrade

My client set auto-upgrade for a component "Smart form golder' component.
After the auto upgrade, Akeeba components stop working.

It throws fatal error in administrator component page -

> Fatal error: Access level to AkeebasubsToolbar::renderSubmenu() must be public (as in class FOFToolbar) in /public_html/administrator/components/com_akeebasubs/toolbar.php on line 358

But the front end working fine, when I checked with Akeeba support forum, they said that it requires upgrade. I customize the component so I am not willing to do also the upgrade can be done through Joomla admin panel and the page are not loading properly. So I am not sure how to fix this.

Please help me.

Comment: if you have customized the component and aren't willing to do an upgrade then you're pretty much stuck. This is why customizations should be done using plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply reinstall the modified version of the fof your version of Akeeba component came from. Your new component "smart form golder" may stop working.

**fof** - "framework on framework" is now integrated in Joomla since version 3.2.  It was developed by Akeeba and ships with all their components; alas it changed a lot between versions, you usually need the exact version the component shipped with.

Comment: Is the downgrade of Smart form golder will fix the issue? Please comment.

Comment: You'd be better off starting over from a backup, or uninstalling the Smart form golder and reinstalling the right version (careful: uninstalling may wipe your db configuration of smart form, make a backup)

Comment: Guys, fatal error in com_akeebasubs is a bug of com_akeebasubs. There is nothing to do with SmartFormer gold

Comment: @nico Apparently smartformer installed a version of fof which was not compatible with akeebasubs, so it seems the issue was with the smartformer installation, not with smartformer itself

Comment: There are a lot of similar errors in google. Just run search for "Fatal error: Access level to AkeebasubsToolbar::renderSubmenu() must be public (as in class FOFToolbar)". The people reporting the error do not have smartformer installed.

Comment: Of course: the issue is an incompatible version of fof, but not only akeeba and smartforms use it: its use is so widespread that it was introduced in the Joomla core